# Image upload form not posting input value when auto submitting form

Tags: php, forms, upload, image-uploading

I am trying to create an avatar uploader, but I want to be able to click only one button that opens the browsing window and then automatically calls the upload method from the `AvatarUpload` class.

The problem I have identified is that the form doesn't seem to be posting anything.

Any help would be great!

```
var_dump(isset($_POST['uploaded']));
if( isset($_POST['uploaded']) ) 
{ 
 $img = new AvatarUpload(); 
 $img->startUpload(); 
} 
else 
{ 
 ?>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadAvatar">
          <p> 
          <input type="file" name="uploaded" id="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
          <p> 
       </form>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you upload files they are listed under the $_FILES, not $_POST.

Comment: Also, unless you have a variable on the form called "uploaded" and it is set to something, that if statement and var dump will do nothing? i there more code?

Comment: cool .. glad to be of help - i stare at code for hours and don't see the missing colon or quote :)